# ArrayOutOfBoundsException with Base Conversion

Tags: java, arrays, exception, converters, radix

For my program, I am trying to convert a number from a base to another a base. However, I am trying to figure out why I keep getting the ArrayOutOfBoundsException. Can anyone help? I am using 21 as the number, 10 as the original base, and then 2 as the new base.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Enter original number
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    Double num = input.nextDouble();
    String orgNum = String.valueOf(num);

    //Enter original base
    System.out.println("Enter its base: ");
    int b = input.nextInt();

    //Enter new base
    System.out.println("Enter base to be converted to: ");
    int a = input.nextInt();

    input.close();

    //Conversion
    String newNum = convertBase(orgNum, b, a);

    //New number
    System.out.println("New Number: " + newNum);
}

public static String convertBase(String orgNum, int b, int a)
{
    double value = 0;
    double decDigit = 0;
    char chDigit;

    int length = orgNum.length();
    for (int p = 0; p < length; p ++)
    {
        chDigit = Character.toUpperCase(orgNum.charAt(length - 1 - p));

        if(Character.isLetter(chDigit))
        {
            decDigit = chDigit - 'A' + 10;
        }
        else if (Character.isDigit(chDigit))
        {
            decDigit = chDigit - '0';
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Digit is unrecognizable.");
        }

        value += decDigit + Math.pow(b, p);
    }
    int D = 1;
    for (D = 1; Math.pow(a, D) <= value; D++) {}

    char[] newNum = new char[D];

    double pwr;
    for (int p = D - 1; p >= 0; D--)
    {
        pwr = Math.pow(a, p);
        decDigit = Math.floor(value / pwr);
        value -= decDigit*pwr;

        if (decDigit <= 9)
        {
            newNum[D - 1 - p] = (char) ('0' + (int)decDigit);
        }
        else
        {
            newNum[D - 1 - p] = (char) ('0' + (int)decDigit - 10);
        }       
    }
    return new String(newNum);
}
```

Comment: Can you add a comment in the code where you are getting the exception?

Comment: for (int p = D - 1; p >= 0; D--) this looks fishy. Shouldn't it be for (int p = D - 1; p >= 0; p--) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple errors I've seen on your code,

a) You should use nextInt instead of nextDouble, and store the value in an primitive integer type;

```
//Enter original number
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
//Double num = input.nextDouble();
int num = input.nextInt();
String orgNum = String.valueOf(num);
```

b) Instead of D, you should decrement p here;

```
        double pwr;
//      for (int p = D - 1; p >= 0; D--)
        for (int p = D - 1; p >= 0; p--)
        {
```

I didn't check that if the output is valid or not, but the modified version below is working fine;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Enter original number
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
//      Double num = input.nextDouble();            // #1: Convert to primitive integer
        int num = input.nextInt();
        String orgNum = String.valueOf(num);

        //Enter original base
        System.out.println("Enter its base: ");
        int b = input.nextInt();

        //Enter new base
        System.out.println("Enter base to be converted to: ");
        int a = input.nextInt();

        input.close();

        //Conversion
        String newNum = convertBase(orgNum, b, a);

        //New number
        System.out.println("New Number: " + newNum);
    }

    public static String convertBase(String orgNum, int b, int a)
    {
        double value = 0;
        double decDigit = 0;
        char chDigit;

        int length = orgNum.length();
        for (int p = 0; p < length; p ++)
        {
            chDigit = Character.toUpperCase(orgNum.charAt(length - 1 - p));

            if(Character.isLetter(chDigit))
            {
                decDigit = chDigit - 'A' + 10;
            }
            else if (Character.isDigit(chDigit))
            {
                decDigit = chDigit - '0';
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Digit is unrecognizable.");
            }

            value += decDigit + Math.pow(b, p);
        }
        int D = 1;
        for (D = 1; Math.pow(a, D) <= value; D++) {}

        char[] newNum = new char[D];

        double pwr;
//      for (int p = D - 1; p >= 0; D--)    // #2: decrement the index p
        for (int p = D - 1; p >= 0; p--)
        {
            pwr = Math.pow(a, p);
            decDigit = Math.floor(value / pwr);
            value -= decDigit*pwr;

            if (decDigit <= 9)
            {
                newNum[D - 1 - p] = (char) ('0' + (int)decDigit);
            }
            else
            {
                newNum[D - 1 - p] = (char) ('0' + (int)decDigit - 10);
            }       
        }
        return new String(newNum);
    }

}
```